# WP How do I customize a specific thumbnail size using CSS class

Tags: css, wordpress

I've tried add_image_size to do my custom thumbnail resize but for some reason it won't stand the thumbnail being 220 x 220 and it will change the height to 167 x, for this I've been trying to do a CSS-based solution instead, which I suppose to work perfectly.

My thumbnail code

```
<?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail(); 
        endif; ?>
```

the css class I need help applying to the thumbnail code above:

```
.imgclass{
height: 220px;
width: 220px;
}
```

Thanks to all the coders out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find thumbnail url & give css to that

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img_thumb"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify what image size you are using as the thumbnail.

```
<?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
    the_post_thumbnail('IMAGE SIZE NAME'); 
endif; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can completely reset the base thumbnail size like so:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 220, 220 );
```

Comment: I did exactly this and the height was never 220, but 146 or so. I've already given up trying on PHP, I believe a simple CSS class will do the treat, just need help getting it applied to the thumbnail code I posted above.. And hey, I don't want to reset the base thumbnail because I want to set a custom size only for a specific thumbnail and not for the rest of the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
            $thumb_attrs = array( 'class' => "imgclass") ;
            the_post_thumbnail($thumb_attrs); 
      endif; ?>
```

Should work.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, but the thumbnail output size [150 x 150] was different from what's defined in the class [220 x 220]. The solution from Jivani worked good, thank you again for trying to help me :)